# WebView - intercepting form submission with javascript enabled

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a problem intercepting form submission in WebView when javascript is enabled. I created a small example to demonstrate this problem.

**test1.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Test 1</h1>
    <form action="http://111.222.33.44/test/test2.html" method="get">
      <input type="text" name="text1" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**TestActivity**

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("Test app", "Intercepted");
                return true;
            }

        });
        webView.loadUrl("http://111.222.33.44/test/test1.html");
    }

}
```

When I run this app on Android 4.x message "Intercepted" is printed when I click on submit button. When I run this app on Android 2.1 - 2.3.x the message is not printed.

How can I intercept form submission on Android 2.1 - 2.3.x?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround is to make the following change in html file:

instead of

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

use

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="this.form.submit();"/>
```