# Android webview: show progress bar on POST submit

Tags: android, webview

I have an app with a webview that shows a series of static pages, one of which has a form. Now to switch between these pages, I show my own custom progress wheel, I override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` like this:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url)
{
    enableLoadingLayer();
    view.loadUrl(url);
}
```

And then I disable the layer on the `OnProgressChanged` event in my `WebChromeClient`.

The problem is, when the user submits my form, the webview does not go through shouldOverrideUrlLoading and thus I can't activate my progress wheel. Is there any way that I can catch this event in my webview?

Comment: Maybe this post will help you:
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784993/webview-intercepting-form-submission-with-javascript-enabled

Comment: thanks for your answer. That works for GET forms, but not POST forms.

Comment: Maybe you can invoke a JS-function on onClick-Event (submit-button) which itself invokes your enableLoadingLayer-method by using JavascriptInterface: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Here is a example of mine posted in a similar context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406467/php-to-android-using-httppost/21406827#21406827